# TSocket read 0 bytes

Tags: python, rpc, thrift

Right, so I have a complete `Python` implementation of a `Thrift` server-client system on my local machine.

It works fine otherwise, until I try and return a string from one of the methods on the server.

**Thrift file**

```
  service HelloWorld {
  void ping(),
  void sayHello(),
  i32 sayMsg(1:string msg)
}
```

It's `sayMsg` which is failing at the return statement.

**server.py**

```
def sayMsg(self, msg):
    print "sayMsg(" + msg + ")" #This line runs fine
    return "say " + msg + " from " + str(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
```

When I run **client.py** the first time, I also get an error `No handlers could be found for logger "thrift.server.TServer"` on the `server` side.

From the next run onwards, this error disappears, but the `TSocket read 0 bytes` persists.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is this question still relevant?

Answer (score 0):

It seems Thrift file error, sayMsg return should be a string not a int_32, change it:

```
service HelloWorld {
  void ping(),
  void sayHello(),
  string sayMsg(1:string msg)
}
```

works.